# Inviting friends to join your game room in Photon Unity Networking

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-sdk-4.0, photon

Hi I have an online multiplayer game running. I can find random opponents and play with them. I am using photon unity networking for this purpose. I want to create a system in which a user can invite his facebook friends who have the game and they could play with each other. I know abt Facebook sdk and how to send requests with it but i want to send push notifications directly to the app instead of facebook and when the user clicks the notification it should open the and user should be redirected to the gameroom. How would i be able to achieve that

Comment: Try Parse Push maybe? https://parse.com/products/push

Comment: Do you use Facebook SDK for Unity? If yes, why it does not work for you?